# NoClassDefFoundError when compiling a HelloWorld programming to a jar

Tags: java, jar, compilation, noclassdeffounderror, manifest.mf

Here's what I've got.

I've got my 'MyJava' folder which everything is contained in.

```
MyJava/src/a/HelloWorld.java
MyJava/src/b/Inner.java
MyJava/bin/
MyJava/manifest.txt
```

HelloWorld.java:

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Hello, World");

        Inner myInner = new Inner(); 
        myInner.myInner(); 
    }
}
```

Inner.java:

```
public class Inner {

    public void myInner() {
        System.out.println("Inner Method");
    }
}
```

Manifest.txt:

```
Main-Class: HelloWorld
```

First I compile the .javas to .class:

`javac -d bin src/a/HelloWorld.java src/b/Inner.java`

Now I put these into a .jar file
`jar cvfm myTwo.jar manifest.txt bin/*.class`

now I try run the jar:
`java -jar myTwo.jar`

And I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HelloWorld
...
Could not find the main class: HelloWorld. Program will exit.
```

I know this is a pretty simple problem, what am I missing?

Comment: It's not part of a package.

Comment: Why are the two classes in different directories?

Comment: Well... I'm playing around with working out how I'd compile for something. Though the something similar does use packages.

Comment: Packages in Java source on the local file system usually correspond to the directory in which the source is kept.  So if a class had package `pkg.name` & name `MyClass` it should be in path a `pkg/name/MyClass.java`.  I recommend if your classes are both in the same package (the default package it seems) they should be in the same directory.  There are ways to do it differently, but I suggest you stick with the simplest way for the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you examine the files inside your .JAR you will notice that your compiled classes are inside the `bin` directory (and therefore cannot be found, since your manifest references a class in the top level).
Change your `jar...`  command like this:

```
jar cvfm myTwo.jar manifest.txt -C bin .
```

See also the **["Creating a JAR File" section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html)** of the Java Tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions is to add the following line to the manifest.txt

```
Class-Path: bin/
```

Then you can use 'your' command for the jar creation:

```
jar cvfm myTwo.jar manifest.txt bin/*.class
```